# Dialogflow error Authorization failed. Please check your access keys

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I have test for dialogflow with android. It was work well a few days ago.

but Nowdays It is occured

```
Caused by: ai.api.AIServiceException: Authorization failed. Please check your access keys.
    at ai.api.AIDataService.request(AIDataService.java:205)
    at ai.api.AIDataService.request(AIDataService.java:148)
    at ai.api.AIDataService.request(AIDataService.java:124)
```

I didn't chagne anythings about clientkey and I was check
clientKey Android or Dialogflow Page. It is same

Why it occur? 
does Dialogflow add SHA1 key? something like certificate?

Comment: Did you check other threads?

Comment: Maybe related with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907605/sudden-forbidden-access

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
My solution:
1. Export your Agent that doesn't work (zip file)
2. Create a new Agent and import the Agent which  you just exported.