# Sudden forbidden access

Tags: dialogflow-es

Since this morning, all our ChatBot using DialogFlow get denied with a response code 403 and the following JSON :

```
{"status":{"code":401,"errorType":"unauthorized","errorDetails":"You are not authorized for this operation. Invalid access token"}}
```

We tried to update the client access token for one of them but without any change.
Note that the responseCode is different that the one specified in the JSON.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be an issue with the service itself. There is already a thread in the official community forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/CEZE6HS4C4o;context-place=forum/dialogflow

You are not alone...

Comment: FYI : I received a mail from DialogFlow saying that it was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what Andrey Kotkovets said in this thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/CEZE6HS4C4o;context-place=forum/dialogflow
and it worked. You need to export your bots and import them as v1 for now.

edit: I created new agents and imported the old ones, I didn't overwrite the old ones.

Comment: Thanks but can't do that as some of them belong to other persons who won't take time to do it. Let's hope for a quick fix by DialogFlow