# Error 401 unauthorized

Tags: dialogflow-es

My bot was working perfectly until now, I am suddenly getting an error  called Unauthorized from API.ai I checked my Heroku logs and this is what I found

Any ideas are appreciated

```
2018-08-18T14:27:59.087498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/messages" host=zupcoin.herokuapp.com request_id=7d2de5a3-05f8-414a-a28e-5cc3e43ab578 fwd="40.121.92.251" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=596ms status=202 bytes=199 protocol=https

{ Error

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/apiai/module/json_api_request.js:59:25)

    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)

    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)

    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)

    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)

    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

  statusCode: 403,

  responseBody: '{"status":{"code":401,"errorType":"unauthorized","errorDetails":"You are not authorized for this operation. Invalid access token"}}',

  name: 'ServerError',

  message: 'Wrong response status code.' }

Error

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/apiai/module/json_api_request.js:59:25)

    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)

    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)

    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)

    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)

    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: Have you reauthenticate?

Comment: Did you check other threads? sounds similar to following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907605/sudden-forbidden-access

Comment: Thanks for the link, just came across this thread